# node.js require cannot find custom module

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, require

Here is the project structure:

```
/
  app.js
  package.json
  /node_modules
  /app
    config.json
    /frontend
      assets and html tpls
    /modules
      couch.js
      raeume.js
      users.js
```

I require config.json, raeume.js and users.js from app.js and it all works fine.

```
var config   = require('./app/config');
var raeume   = require('./app/modules/raeume');
var users    = require('./app/modules/users');
```

Then I require config.json and couch.js from user.js the same way and it won't find anything.

```
var couch     = require('./app/modules/couch');
var config    = require('./app/config');
```

I guess it should find it. After some research I saw a diverse landscape of problems inclusive how node is compiled. Thus included: I work on osx 10.8 with node v0.10.7.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The path is relative to the directory in which you are `require`ing the files, so it should be something like:

```
var couch = require('./couch');
var config = require('../config');
```

A bit of clarification, if you write

```
var couch = require('./couch');
```

you are trying to `require` the couch module which resides in the current directory, if you write

```
var couch = require('couch');
```

you are trying to `require` the couch module installed via `npm`.

Comment: I try relative:

var couch     = require('couch');
var config    = require('../config');

finds config but not couch.

Comment: You missed the `./` in `require('couch');`

Comment: I doesn't work with me: when I do either `require('qmlweb')` or `require('./node_modules/qmlweb')`, it says the module cannot be found. Yet qmlweb is installed in node_modules/qmlweb, and all the files are there.

Comment: Please open a new question posting your relevant information, such as a snippet with your code and the likes, link it here if you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652662) is correct and properly answers the question.

Although not directly related to the original question, I'd like to add another point here for all those people who got the `Cannot find module` error for local files although the correct relative path was specified.

Assuming a file with the name `couch.js` exists in the current directory,

- On case insensitive filesystems (like NTFS on Windows), both these lines will work -

  ```
  var couch = require('./couch');
  var couch = require('./Couch');
  ```
- However, on a case-sensitive filesystem (like ext4 on Linux), `require('./couch')` will work but `require('./Couch')` will not.

There is [a page in the NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/working-with-different-filesystems/) regarding this.

I hope this helps someone whose perfectly working code stopped working after moving from Windows/Mac to Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do it :

```
var users    = require('./../modules/users');
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be:

```
var config = require(../../app/config)

var couch = require(./couch) (same directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also double check the extension on the file being imported. I accidentally used `.ts` in a JavaScript project, and this prevented it from being found. Once I changed the extension to `.js`, `require` was able to find it fine.