# Typescript compiles successfully but node cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, tsconfig-paths, typescript-module-resolution

Node error `Error: Cannot find module 'hello'` even though Typescript compiled successfully.

Dir structure (note this is almost identical to [tsconfig docs for baseUrl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl))

```
main
| src
| ├─ index.ts
| └─ hello
|      └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
└── package.json
```

I want to only use non-relative imports (so no `/`, `./`, `../`). I've encountered this problem in the past and have always resorted to using relative imports, but I do not want to continue doing this.

In the top level `index.ts` there is `import { helloWorld } from 'hello'`.

`tsc` compiles successfully and the output dir `dist` looks like this:

```
main
├─ src
├─ tsconfig.json
├─ package.json
└─ dist
    ├─ index.js
    └─ hello
        └── index.js
```

Running `node dist/index.js` outputs the error `Error: Cannot find module 'hello'`. The import statement gets compiled in `dist/index.js` to `require("hello")` which is where the error is thrown.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652662/14629378), it seems like `require()` will only look at modules in the current directory if the path begins with `./`. So when I change it to `require("./hello")` it works completely fine!

I've been playing around with `baseUrl` and `paths` in `tsconfig.json` but I cannot get it to output `require("./hello")`. Would really appreciate some help on this issue and to finally get to the bottom of it, thanks!

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // from extending off "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json"
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // end of @tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: if you `import { ... } from './hello'` it should compile to `const ... = require('./hello')`. Importing (either via `require` or `import` from `'hello'` will make node look for the module in `node_modules`. I *think* this is down to now node resolves modules and not a TS specific thing

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos, but I want to avoid using relative imports. I've seen and worked in projects that only use non-relative imports so this should be possible.

Comment: Paste the content of hello/index.ts

Comment: @RohitChoudhary It's just `export const helloWorld = "hello world"`. Node can't find the module so it has not loaded the contents of that file yet - the contents of the file should be irrelevant.

Comment: If you look at tsconfig.json, the `compilerOptions.paths` key, you'll see how you can map module names into your directory structure.

Comment: @DaveMeehan Following the docs for `compilerOptions.paths`, if I have an entry `"hello/*": ["hello/*"]`, with the `baseUrl: "src"` it still gives me the same error - tsc compiles, but node errors. I've tried many variants of it as well and still cannot get it to work. If possible, could you provide a working example?

Comment: Check the generated JS by typescript, you may also need to configure module resolution in node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that this is topic has received a lot of attention in Typescript's Github issues. A few of many issues raised about this very problem:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866

[From the TS Lead himself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722#issuecomment-524375687):

> Our general take on this is that you should write the import path that works at runtime, and set your TS flags to satisfy the compiler's module resolution step, rather than writing the import that works out-of-the-box for TS and then trying to have some other step "fix" the paths to what works at runtime.

So it seems like we either use relative imports, or use some tool like `tsc-alias`.